# Deploying multiple React applications in one Node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I have multiple portfolios made in React and each one of them has their own Node.js API.

I'd like to gather all frontends in only one domain so all I would have to do is using "/name-of-the-project" for each one of them. I did the steps below:

1. Created a new Node.js server that will work as a "general server";
2. In this general server, I set the folder public to be used for static files;
3. Built any of the React apps (npm run build);
4. Moved the deploy codes to the public folder of the general server;
5. Set the cors() in the API's (the ones I mentioned React apps were built with) of the frontends to allow requests from the general;

An example of how the general server became with a React deploy:

[image]

When I access http://localhost, it works. But remember I said I had multiple projects? So I created folders inside the public folder to put each React deploy in their respective folder. Let's say:

[image]

Now if I enter http://localhost/frontend-1, for example, it doesn't work

[image]

**What I tried to do before creating this question?**

I created a simple index.html inside each folder and they work. Only React deploys don't.

If it helps anyway, this is the general Node.js code:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are missing is the setting up the basename's of each of the react apps that you have.. I assume that you have routing in each of your application, with that you have to update its `basename` to point into the right directory/url.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I was building an e-commerce store with 2 separate apps  - customer and admin apps.

I believe in your case the issue is that the `npm run build` doesn't have the relative path. 
For instance, all the static files like `.css` in `frontend-1` app should be prepended by `/frontend-1` and same for others. \

To do this update the build script in your individual react apps and add `PUBLIC_URL`. For example in [this code block](https://github.com/the-mentalist/serve-multiple-apps-guide/blob/main/admin/package.json#L16) i have added that for an admin app.

For more detailed explanation you can refer this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Utq4cTuyshw).